# The right way to delete file to trash in Snow Leopard using Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

I mean the right way must able to "Put Back" in Finder and isn't playing sound

Here are the methods I tried so far:

```
NSString * name  = @"test.zip";
 NSArray  * files = [NSArray arrayWithObject: name];

 NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];

 [ws performFileOperation: NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation
       source: @"/Users/"
     destination: @""
        files: files
       tag: 0];
```

Downturn : can't "Put Back" in Finder

```
OSStatus status = FSPathMoveObjectToTrashSync(
              "/Users/test.zip",
              NULL,
              kFSFileOperationDefaultOptions
 );
```

Downturn : can't "Put Back" in Finder

```
tell application "Finder"
    set deletedfile to alias "Snow Leopard:Users:test.zip"
    delete deletedfile
end tell
```

Downturn : playing sound so it's annoying if I execute it repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want "put back" then applescript is the way to go. I was able to do it without any sound by muting the volume, moving the file, then unmuting the volume. Note I needed a delay to get it to work.

```
set f to (path to desktop folder as text) & "myFile.txt"
set volume with output muted
tell application "Finder" to move file f to trash
delay 1
set volume without output muted
```

Comment: Are you muting the system volume? If so if the user is currently playing music, he/she will notice that the music goes silent for a while.